# Замена forEach для IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на сайте работает замечательный скрипт, который по ip определяет страну и телефонный код пользователя и отдает эти данные в скрытое поле.

К сожалению, скрипт не работает в IE 11, т.к. использует ES6.

Я сконвертировал код в Babel, но пока эта конструкция не работает.

Сначала, отладчик IE ругался на forEach в строке:

```js
targets.forEach(function (target) {
  return observer.observe(target, options);
});
```

я ее заменил на :

```js
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) { return observer.observe(targets[i], options);}
```

Теперь отладчик выдает ошибку: "Инструкция 'return' вне функции"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Полный код:

```js
"use strict";

$("[data-type='phone'] .input .form-control").intlTelInput({

  allowDropdown: true,
  autoPlaceholder: "aggressive",
  initialCountry: "auto",
  geoIpLookup: function geoIpLookup(success, failure) {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function () {}, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
      var countryCode = resp && resp.country ? resp.country : "";
      success(countryCode);
    });
  }
});

var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.selected-flag'),
    options = {
  'attributes': true
},
    observationHandler = function observationHandler(mutations, observer) {
  for (var _iterator = mutations, _isArray = Array.isArray(_iterator), _i = 0, _iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : _iterator[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
    var _ref;

    if (_isArray) {
      if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
      _ref = _iterator[_i++];
    } else {
      _i = _iterator.next();
      if (_i.done) break;
      _ref = _i.value;
    }

    var mutation = _ref;

    var target = mutation.target,
        recipient = target.closest('div.fields').querySelector('[data-type="hidden"] input');
    recipient.value = target.title;
  }
},
    observer = new MutationObserver(observationHandler);

targets.forEach(function (target) {
  return observer.observe(target, options);
});
```

```css
.field {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.form-control {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/css/intlTelInput.css">
<h2>Main form on page</h2>
<div class="fields">
  <div class="field" data-type="phone" style="width: 247px;">
    <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" style="border-radius: 15px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field" data-type="hidden" style="width: 247px;">
    <div class="input"><input class="form-control" type="text" style="border-radius: 15px;" value="hidden content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL FORM 1 -->
<h2>Modal form 1</h2>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="macros-form">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="vertical none size-default">
          <div class="body">
            <div class="cont"></div>
            <form class="form text-top" data-form=""
              data-fields="">
              <div class="fields">
                <div class="field" data-type="phone">
                  <div class="name">Telefonnummer</div>
                  <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" style="border-radius: 4px;"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="field hidden" data-type="hidden">
                  <div class="input"><input class="form-control hidden-field" value="Hidden field"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="cont"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- MODAL FORM 2 -->
<h2>Modal form 2</h2>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="macros-form">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="vertical none size-default">
          <div class="body">
            <div class="cont"></div>
            <form class="form text-top" data-form=""
              data-fields="">
              <div class="fields">
                <div class="field" data-type="phone">
                  <div class="name">Telefonnummer</div>
                  <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" style="border-radius: 4px;"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="field hidden" data-type="hidden">
                  <div class="input"><input class="form-control hidden-field" value="Hidden field"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="macros-button">
                <div class="btn-out full xs-none">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="cont"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/intlTelInput-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/utils.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kerm131/xpvt214o/984507/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если что-то не хватает - сначала поищи полифил. Кстати вот он https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

Попробуй сборку полифилов

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

или [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/).

Потом не нужен тут `return`. Убери это слово и заработает.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. В других браузерах все нормально, в IE11 та же проблема. https://jsfiddle.net/kerm131/mjs8pb1q/ Добавил полифил, но отладчик по-прежнему ругается на forEach

Comment: попробуй убрать ретурн и оставь с for. ретурн там просто не нужен

Comment: Полифилл должен стоять выше места, где вызывается неподдерживаемый метод (на всякий случай указываю это).

Comment: @NeedHate так и сделал)) он размещен в самом начале скрипта

Comment: @AntonKuzmich, смотри вопрос дубликат :-)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Твой совет помог, все заработало